# Can't login to phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am unable to log into phpMyAdmin after installation. Here is my config.inc.php file. Am I doing something obviously wrong? I'm sorry, this is the first time I'm dealing with PHP, MySQL, etc. Thanks for your help!

```
    <?php
    /* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */

    /**
    * phpMyAdmin sample configuration, you can use it as base for
    * manual configuration. For easier setup you can use setup/
    *
    * All directives are explained in Documentation.html and on phpMyAdmin
    * wiki <http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net>.
    *
    * @package phpMyAdmin
    */

   /*
    * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
    * cookie
    */
   $cfg['blowfish_secret'] = ''; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

   /*
    * Servers configuration
    */
   $i = 0;

   /*
    * First server
    */
   $i++;
   /* Authentication type */
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
   /* Server parameters */
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'chillysky.com';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'user';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
   /* Select mysqli if your server has it */
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

   /*
    * phpMyAdmin configuration storage settings.
    */

   /* User used to manipulate with storage */
   // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
   // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pmapass';

   /* Storage database and tables */
   // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
   // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
   // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
   // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
   // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
/* Contrib / Swekey authentication */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_swekey_config'] = '/etc/swekey-pma.conf';

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

/*
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

/**
 * Defines whether a user should be displayed a "show all (records)"
 * button in browse mode or not.
 * default = false
 */
//$cfg['ShowAll'] = true;

/**
 * Number of rows displayed when browsing a result set. If the result
 * set contains more rows, "Previous" and "Next".
 * default = 30
 */
//$cfg['MaxRows'] = 50;

/**
 * Use graphically less intense menu tabs
 * default = false
 */
//$cfg['LightTabs'] = true;

/**
 * disallow editing of binary fields
 * valid values are:
 *   false  allow editing
 *   'blob' allow editing except for BLOB fields
 *   'all'  disallow editing
 * default = blob
 */
//$cfg['ProtectBinary'] = 'false';

/**
 * Default language to use, if not browser-defined or user-defined
 * (you find all languages in the locale folder)
 * uncomment the desired line:
 * default = 'en'
 */
//$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
//$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'de';

/**
 * default display direction (horizontal|vertical|horizontalflipped)
 */
//$cfg['DefaultDisplay'] = 'vertical';


/**
 * How many columns should be used for table display of a database?
 * (a value larger than 1 results in some information being hidden)
 * default = 1
 */
//$cfg['PropertiesNumColumns'] = 2;

/**
 * Set to true if you want DB-based query history.If false, this utilizes
 * JS-routines to display query history (lost by window close)
 *
 * This requires configuration storage enabled, see above.
 * default = false
 */
//$cfg['QueryHistoryDB'] = true;

/**
 * When using DB-based query history, how many entries should be kept?
 *
 * default = 25
 */
//$cfg['QueryHistoryMax'] = 100;

/*
 * You can find more configuration options in Documentation.html
 * or here: http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config
 */
?>
```

Comment: What happens or doesn't happen? What do you see when you open the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, I really haven't dealt with MySQL or PHP before, but the problem was that the root user didn't have a password, and my config.inc.php file was set to not accept a blank password, so it was impossible to log in. I changed my password and it nows works.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this line

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = ''; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */
```

and this.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

I'm thinking you have to enter a password there like this:

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'YOURPASSWORD'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It's not so much a password as a random string. Using your password for something else there would be ill advised.